# React render object value where key is variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, jsx, rendering

I'm trying to render an object where each key is different.
I have to display each key as a checkbox and if it is checked, I want to display the associated values if any in the values array.

My object structure is as follows:

```
    myObj: {
           "key1": ["val1", "val2"],
           "key2": [],
           ...
           }
```

I'm going through the list of keys to render the checkboxes and within, I'm using the code below for rendering the values.
I have the value of the current key accessible in a property `myKey.value`. But if I try to use `formValues.myObj.myKey.value` to access the values, it complains that property `myKey` does not exist on type `myObj`.

```
{formValues.myObj.[`${currentKey}`].length > 0 && 
    <CustomArrayHelper
    values={formValues.myObj.currentKey}
    arrayName="test"
    onRender={(avIndex: number) => (
        <div className="my-container std-TextField">
            <FormikTextField
                name={`test.${avIndex}`}
                label={`Test`}
            />
        </div>
    )}
/>}
```

I need some way to dynamically specify the current key to get the values for each key. The above code returns an error.

I also have the list of possible keys available separately:

```
export const MyKeys = [
    {
        value: 'key1',
        label: 'key1'
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access values using computed property keys you need to use the bracket notation.

```
<CustomArrayHelper values={formValues.myObj[currentKey]} />
```

Also, you shouldn't put a `dot` when accessing properties using bracket notation, that's a syntax error. You can also remove the string template syntax, that's unnecessary.

```
formValues.myObj[currentKey].length
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! The change you suggested for the `name` field however, gives me a `cannot find name 'test'` error, but keeping it the way I have it in the question works.

Comment: Great! Consider accepting & upvoting the answer if it solved your problem. You can ignore that suggestion if it doesn't work, I just made a guess there because I'm not aware of your entire code.

Comment: I've removed that part from my answer to avoid any confusion.